# Finding average of the smallest 4 values in an array which generates 200 random numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code run in the spyder IDE:

```
idnum = 201034628
seed(idnum);
w = np.random.rand(200)
print(w)
```

This generates the following result:

```
[0.00176212 0.79092217 0.1759531  0.00239256 0.78842458 0.30404404
 0.25633004 0.88271124 0.72031936 0.17356416 0.5674158  0.83897948
 0.4133943  0.22471237 0.66562002 0.70207085 0.55722598 0.86308392
 0.14584968 0.66224337 0.79900625 0.2687224  0.45508786 0.99014178
 0.176943   0.42335567 0.41034833 0.75497287 0.41301282 0.11294302
 0.58715198 0.01524138 0.58633177 0.9784454  0.14610789 0.68654175
 0.94733177 0.93776749 0.17294272 0.7491281  0.94087871 0.60510781
 0.43708462 0.77303273 0.13250525 0.50794632 0.36706808 0.46873059
 0.99757662 0.144249   0.69427544 0.78359245 0.64836852 0.16574067
 0.98633778 0.05613428 0.51713291 0.27246708 0.26216551 0.44605373
 0.99963659 0.90569603 0.31139955 0.25559081 0.8295379  0.84638476
 0.48194161 0.505123   0.57456517 0.62727722 0.11940848 0.49435157
 0.07438197 0.11481526 0.74184931 0.94697125 0.93788422 0.3586455
 0.852594   0.35167897 0.57139446 0.77923007 0.09070311 0.07821641
 0.38140649 0.80945136 0.81820638 0.8140444  0.94458644 0.42983398
 0.06609377 0.25737315 0.27873234 0.87183073 0.14317078 0.8964766
 0.00731705 0.16095917 0.70980283 0.49757526 0.06990482 0.15304861
 0.02710815 0.21319381 0.82069776 0.19839614 0.64250566 0.6383788
 0.12539173 0.74583486 0.11041236 0.827742   0.20340574 0.03643315
 0.62638826 0.12454928 0.64567226 0.04782684 0.88455847 0.62114705
 0.82253557 0.12590787 0.99624612 0.0780055  0.38312778 0.56969024
 0.21771078 0.18022973 0.06825607 0.05189065 0.19410785 0.93458232
 0.84006441 0.8796388  0.00574523 0.92213916 0.60108549 0.48774697
 0.79918579 0.05700109 0.42167703 0.26358089 0.37023659 0.05556867
 0.1788227  0.63840475 0.79772203 0.20969062 0.55459356 0.81425831
 0.06324903 0.274849   0.15092814 0.65504038 0.57138257 0.37113864
 0.84318386 0.58306703 0.95677286 0.28962055 0.31085227 0.92607168
 0.61132872 0.42862182 0.67385059 0.58591843 0.98309858 0.12926512
 0.89650825 0.47853266 0.16842571 0.77785123 0.16004964 0.24379739
 0.76415568 0.14338659 0.73812864 0.52921474 0.8678008  0.82205399
 0.1219327  0.83831355 0.5219863  0.67680272 0.05486754 0.89255115
 0.91609614 0.74104108 0.98763434 0.07343619 0.0879543  0.55360531
 0.01048341 0.01083459 0.13080064 0.51212431 0.24552376 0.77620793
 0.16560353 0.42042389]
```

I need to find the average of the smallest 4 values from the numbers in the w array. How would I do this ?

Comment: simple sort function and slicing will do the trick

Comment: Use `w.sort()` and then `w[:4].mean()`.

Comment: Sorting is overkill--it does more work than necessary.  Take a look at `numpy.partition` (mentioned in my answer).

Comment: Yh thankyou i seen your answer its much quicker than sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) which should be slightly faster than sorting:

```
import heapq
import statistics

print(statistics.mean(heapq.nsmallest(4, w)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
sum(sorted(w)[:4])/len(sorted(w)[:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting the array and select 4 minimum values by slicing and then find mean.

```
np.mean(np.sort(w)[:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) with `kth=3`, and then take the mean of the first four values:

```
In [41]: np.partition(w, 3)[:4].mean()
Out[41]: 0.004304237929249388
```